# Robot Framework - Drive a firefox browser threw an ssh connection

Tags: robotframework

Here is my problem, I am on RedHat7(machine 1) and I need to connect to another RH7 machine (2) where I have to execute web browser automation.
The problem is, after my ssh connection, when I want to use the Selenium Library to Open a browser, it open one on My machine (1)
How can I do to drive web automation through SSH Connection?

Thank you :D

Comment: why dont you just have the test on your second machine in the first place and send just command to execute it through ssh connection?

Comment: I just cant, the machine is not designed to keep test on it